# Date column varies in length between MMS and SMS

Tags: android, date, sms, android-contentprovider, mms

When querying Android's MMS-SMS `Content Provider`, the date column has different epoch time values for MMS as opposed to SMS.

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
final String[] projection = new String[] { "body", "person", "sub",
            "subject", "retr_st", "type", "date" + " as " + "d", "ct_cls", "sub_cs",
            "_id", "read", "ct_l", "st", "msg_box", "reply_path_present",
            "m_cls", "read_status", "ct_t", "status", "retr_txt_cs",
            "d_rpt", "error_code", "m_id", "date_sent", "m_type", "v",
            "exp", "pri", "service_center", "address", "rr", "rpt_a",
            "resp_txt", "locked", "resp_st", "m_size" };
String sortOrder = "date";
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, sortOrder);

String messageDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"));
```

In the case of `MMS`, the epoch time that gets saved in the messageDate variable is 10 digits long.  However, in the case of an `SMS`, the epoch time that gets saved in the messageDate variable is 13 digits long.

This becomes an issue when trying to sort by date since the `MMS` messages show up before `SMS` messages when sorted by date.

Is there any way to query this `Content Provider` and get all messages (`MMS` or `SMS`) sorted by date correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the way to sort messages by date, regardless of whether the message is an MMS or SMS, is to change the sort order to `normalized_date` as follows:

```
String sortOrder = "normalized_date";
```

Comment: Do you know what each of the columns mean?  I want to figure out whether an MMS was sent or received.

Comment: @gonzobrains thanks for editing the answer.  Btw, you can try out the snippet below to determine if an MMS was sent or received.

Comment: private static final int RECIPIENT = 137;
private static final int SENDER = 151;

Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://mms").buildUpon();
builder.appendPath(messageId).appendPath("addr");
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(builder.build(),
  new String[] { "*" }, null, null, null);
while (c.moveToNext()) {
 messageAddress = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));

 if (!messageAddress.equals("insert-address-token")) {
  type = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
  c.moveToLast();
 }
}
c.close();

if (type == RECIPIENT) {
    // ...

} else if (type == SENDER) {
    // ...
}

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this out ASAP.  Did you get those constants by looking in the Android code?  I have tried to register for Intents but I can't seem to determine when an MMS is received, so I am resorting to observing the MMS database.  Unfortunately, I can only observe content://mms-sms/conversations/ as mms/inbox and mms/sent don't seem to work for me.

Comment: I saw a lot of of columns, but none named "address" or "type" in content://mms-sms/conversations/.  Are the columns different for content://mms?

Comment: @gonzobrains These are the columns for Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + mThreadId); :   String[] projection = new String[] { "body", "person", "sub", "subject", "retr_st", "type", "date", "ct_cls", "sub_cs","_id", "read", "ct_l", "st", "msg_box", "reply_path_present", "m_cls", "read_status", "ct_t", "status", "retr_txt_cs", "d_rpt", "error_code", "m_id", "date_sent", "m_type", "v", "exp", "pri", "service_center", "address", "rr", "rpt_a", "resp_txt", "locked", "resp_st", "m_size" };

Comment: You can upvote the question or answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work.  What if I don't know the thread ID?  Also, how do I know if it is an MMS or an SMS?

Comment: @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    mCursor = getCursor();
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    int type = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
    return type;
}

Comment: private static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL = 0;
 private static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
 private static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  int type = getItemViewType(position);


  if (type == MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX) {
   //SMS INBOX
  } else if (type == MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT) {
            //SMS OUTBOX
        } else if (type == MESSAGE_TYPE_ALL) {
            //MMS
        }

    }